# Use a saved expression inside another expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
        public static Expression<Func<EntityA, bool>> IsAGood =
            x => x.A != null &&
            x.A.valid;

        public static Expression<Func<EntityB, bool>> IsBGood=
            x => IsAGood (x.EntityA);

        var res = context.EntitiesB
                 .Where(x => x.count > 0)
                 .Where(IsBGood)
```

I know I can compile IsAGood and run it on x.EntityA but it loads the data to memory and I don't want to do this yet.
Is there a way to do this without loading to memory?

Comment: so you want to create a lazy object? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-5.0  Scroll down to the remarks section

Comment: ill check that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with some [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) processing. Maybe there are easier ways to do this, but the one I know looks something like this (you can place this code in static constructor):

```
Expression<Func<EntityB, EntityA>> exp = b => b.EntityA;
var param = exp.Parameters.First();
var expression = new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(new[]{IsAGood.Parameters.First()}, new []{exp.Body}).Visit(IsAGood.Body);
IsBGood = Expression.Lambda<Func<EntityB, bool>>(expression, param);
```

[`ReplacingExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.replacingexpressionvisitor?view=efcore-5.0) is available since EF Core 3.0, if you are using an older version you can write you own one, it should not be that hard.

Also you can try using `Expression.Inkove` (but I think I had some issues with it being translated previously):

```
Expression<Func<EntityB, EntityA>> exp = b => b.EntityA;
var param = exp.Parameters.First();
IsBGood = Expression.Lambda<Func<EntityB, bool>>(Expression.Invoke(IsAGood, exp.Body), param);
```

Comment: I doubt that this will work, since to access a property in another entity we will need a join or a sub-query. Note that `x` in `x.EntityA` refers to `EntityB`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes AFAIK EF is capable of figuring out if join is needed without user manually specifying this join.

Comment: Good to know! EF gets better and better.

Comment: Thanks!
the second solution is not working on linq to entities (the invoke..)
does the first solution work on EF6 as well?
getting compilation error: 'ReplacingExpressionVisitor' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Comment: changed the arrays to dictionary and it worked :) thanks! and its not loading to memory right?

Comment: @SagiCohen glad it helped! You should able to check generated SQL query (and I highly recommend you always to do so) and see if it is so.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you cannot call `Compile` on a lambda expression in this context, because this creates a delegate. But EF needs an `Expression` because the o/r-mapper needs the syntax information it contains to convert it into a SQL command. An executable delegate cannot be convert to SQL and cannot be executed by the DB.

---

Now to your concern about loading data into memory.
Neither `IsAGood` nor `IsBGood` nor your combined query loads any data into memory until you actually enumerate the query (e.g. with `.ToList()` or `foreach`).

You can even add parts dynamically as shown here:

```
var query = context.EntitiesB
    .Where(x => x.count > 0); // No data access happens here.
if (useCondition) {
    query = query.Where(IsBGood); // No data access happens here.
}
var result = query.ToList(); // The DB will be accessed here once.
```

Note that all the parts of your code only set up a query. They don't execute any query. Therefore I changed the name of the var from `res` to `query`.

---

Okay I see the problem. `IsAGood` cannot be called like this, since it is an `Expression<>`, not a delegate (and a delegate does not work anyway as I have explained earlier).

You can solve this by rewriting the expression as @GuruStron explains or change the test to

```
public static Expression<Func<EntityB, bool>> IsAinBGood =
        b => b.EntityA.A != null &&
             b.EntityA.A.valid;
```

Comment: I cant actually do: x => IsAGood (x.EntityA);
non invocable member cannot be used like a method

Comment: OP asks about reusing one expression in another, not about conditionally building query.

Comment: His concern is that the precompiled queries (as he calls them) will load data into memory prematurely.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes, if he calls `Compile` on `IsAGood` and uses it in `IsBGood` EF will not be able to handle `IsBGood`, so OP will need to fetch data into the memory.